# css3 :not selector for div and its children

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to apply display:block style to all div tags except one container and all its children using not but I fail, not sure what is wrong.

```
<style>
div:not(.t1 *) {
 display:block
}
</style>

    <div class="t1">some floating content<div class="sub-t1>more floating stuff</div></div>
    <div class="t2">some floating content</div>
    <div class="t3">some floating content</div>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: This might be a small thing, but you're missing an end quote after sub-t1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You Need More Specific Location Target to the `.t1` being Filtered

It was already noted by brian that the `*` in `:not()` is invalid in css.

However, the core problem is that `div:not(.t1)` will match any `div`, *including its children which do **not** have a class of* `.t1`. So it fails even if coupled as `div:not(.t1) div` as [this fiddle example shows](http://jsfiddle.net/LR2L4/2/).

You state in a comment:

> I just want to filter all divs inside specific div without applying
>   the style to the rest of page elements but DIVs only

Basically the only way to get an accurate "filter" by using `:not()` is to relate it also back to the `body` element or some other "fixed" and "unique" element to get a specific *place* in the html structure. So in your sample html, let me assume that it is inside a `#wrapper` div that is directly under the `body` element for this illustration. Then to target all other div's except those in `.t1` what you need is this (**[see fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LR2L4/1/)**):

```css
#wrapper, /* targets wrapper div itself */
#wrapper > div:not(.t1), /* targets all sibling divs to .t1 */
#wrapper > div:not(.t1) div /* targets child divs to any div other than .t1 */
{ display: block; }
```

If your html was directly under the `body`, then this only (**[see fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/LR2L4/)**):

```css
body > div:not(.t1), /* targets all sibling divs to .t1 */
body > div:not(.t1) div /* targets child divs to any div other than .t1 */
{ display: block; }
```

In both cases, the added direct child selector `>` prevents the `:not(.t1)` from being looked at except on the level it exists on. This way, a grandchild `div` element of `.t1` does not get a false reading from its parent `div` (which is itself a child of `.t1`).

If `.t1` is at some random, unknown level in the hierarchy, then a pure css solution is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that a div by default is displayed as a block so you're having the wrong approach. All divs are blocks so you should change the display property of the ones you don't want to be.

For example,

```
div.t1, div.t1 div {
  display: inline;
}
```

Also, to speak strictly css, you cannot put `.t1 *` in the `:not` parameter, as the specification says, it takes only a "simple selector".

So `div:not(.t1)` is ok, `div:not(.t1 *)` is not.

Comment: Well this might be a bit more complicated then just inline style. That is why I was looking for generic solution to filter the entire block of html without need to rewrite it's styles.